# How to prove that limit of intergral of functions convergs to integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

Let be $f: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ Riemann integrable. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ define $a=x_0<x_1<...<x_n = b$ with $x_k=a+\frac{k}{n}(b-a)$ and $\epsilon_k \in [x_{k-1}, x_k] $

Define the functions $f_n: [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ with:

$f_n(x) = f(\epsilon_k)$ if $x \in (x_{k-1}, x_k), k \in {1,...n}$

$f_n(x) = f(x)$ if $x = x_k, k \in {1,...n}$

To prove is that $lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} f(\epsilon_k) = \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx$

Intuitively, I understand what this is about: by making the intervals smaller and smaller, the decomposition becomes finer and the sequence of functions more accurate, so that the integrals become approximately equal.

But I don't know how to show it formally.

My idea would be to show the following:

f is integrable on [a, b] => f is bounded => define functions g and h exactly like $f_n$ but instead of $\epsilon$ choose the supremum and infimum on intervals (from boundedness follows well-definedness).

Further it remains to show that integrals of g and h converge against integral of f, but I don't know exactly how to do it...

Comment: Your result is a special case of the fact that Riemann sums converge to the Riemann integral of a Riemann integrable function (the converse is also true). Your approach is how it is proved. See theorem 4.2.4 on page 132 here https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/anal1v.pdf.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Your strategy of considering lower and upper Darboux sums, $L(f, P)$ and $U(f, P)$, is good. These are not generally Riemann sums for $f$, but are approximated arbitrarily closely by Riemann sums for $f$. Consequently, $U(f, P) - L(f, P)$ can be made as small as we like by taking $P$ sufficiently fine, so $\sup_{P} L(f, P) = \inf_{P} U(f, P)$ exists and is equal to the Riemann integral. Finally, every Riemann sum for the partition $P$ is between the Darboux sums for $P$.

Comment: Thank you! I could simply use here the definition of infimum or supremum to show the statement. I found an alternative solution as well: with epsilon criterion

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

To show: $$\forall_{\epsilon >0} \exists_{N \in \mathbb{N_0}} \forall_{n>N} |\int^{b}_{a}{f(x)dx} - \int^{b}_{a}{f_n(x)}| < \epsilon$$

1. Assume $\epsilon$ is arbitrary. Then from definition of Riemann integral we have the following:

$$ \exists_{u, o (step functions), u \leq f \leq o} \int^{b}_{a} (o-u) dx < \epsilon$$

2. Assume $\zeta$ is the partition of u with $|\zeta| = m$. Then set $n=M$, so:

$$ \forall_{n>m} |\int^{b}_{a}{f(x)dx} - \int^{b}_{a}{f_n(x)}| \leq |\int^{b}_{a}{o(x)dx} - \frac{1}{n} \cdot \sum^{n}_{k=1} u(\epsilon_k)| \leq |\int^{b}_{a}{o(x)dx} - \frac{1}{m} \cdot \sum^{m}_{k=1} u(\epsilon_k)| =$$

$$|\int^{b}_{a} (o-u)dx | < \epsilon$$